# Is there a way to batch delete tables from the console?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

In BigQuery I have daily analytics tables from Firebase. These have built up over time, there are around 600 now. Is there any way in the console to delete all tables that are more than a year old?

If not, is there any other way I can do this? I have enabled a default table expiry now, but am aware that this value only applies moving forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you combine [scripting](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting#bigquery_scripting) with [INFORMATION_SCHEMA](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-tables#tables_view), you can write a SQL like:

```sql
DECLARE pairs ARRAY<STRUCT<tableName STRING, creation_time TIMESTAMP>>;
DECLARE index DEFAULT 0;
SET pairs = (
  SELECT ARRAY_AGG(
    STRUCT<tableName STRING, creation_time TIMESTAMP>(
     CONCAT('`', TABLE_CATALOG, '.', TABLE_SCHEMA, '.', TABLE_NAME, '`'),
     CREATION_TIME
    )
  )
  FROM yourDataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
  WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE');

SELECT pairs; -- print here to make sure you're operating on right set of tables

WHILE index < ARRAY_LENGTH(pairs) DO BEGIN
  DECLARE tableAndCreationTime DEFAULT pairs[OFFSET(index)];
  DECLARE sql DEFAULT FORMAT("ALTER TABLE %s SET OPTIONS (expiration_timestamp=TIMESTAMP '%t')", 
                tableAndCreationTime.tableName, 
                TIMESTAMP_ADD(tableAndCreationTime.creation_time, INTERVAL 365 DAY));
  SELECT sql; -- print again to regret, when ready uncomment next line
  -- EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql;
  SET index = index + 1;
END;
END WHILE;
```

Comment: Thanks for this Yun, it worked. FWIW, I couldn't work out a way to print in the BigQuery SQL syntax. None of the documentation even mentions such capability, only ERROR(), from what I could find.